# type wrong when using sklearn and pandas.Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dataframe, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I want to use sklearn to do some predict  and i stored my data in a Dataframe.

```
Data = DataFrame(columns = columns,index = range(1,501))
```

The data has no problem.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
Xtrain,Xtest,Ytrain,Ytest = train_test_split(Data[columns[0:5]],Data[columns[5:6]],test_size = 0.25,random_state = 33)
```

aslo tried:

```
Xtrain,Xtest,Ytrain,Ytest = train_test_split(np.array(Data[columns[0:5]]),np.array(Data[columns[5:6]]),test_size = 0.25,random_state = 33)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
ss = StandardScaler()
Xtrain = ss.fit_transform(Xtrain)
Xtest = ss.transform(Xtest)
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain)
```

and the wrong message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

    File "/Volumes/sogou_baidu.py", line 148, in <module> 
        lr.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain) 
    File "/Users/liumengyang/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/skl‌​earn/linear_model/lo‌​gistic.py", line 1143, in 
        fit check_classification_targets(y) 
    File "/Users/liumengyang/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/skl‌​earn/utils/multiclas‌​s.py", line 173, in 
        check_classification_targets raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y)

    ValueError: Unknown label type: array([-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -2, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1], dtype=object)
```

Under normal circumstances , the parameters of lr.fit() should be two array , but now use the DataFrame as parameter , there is a redundant parameter “dtype=object” , how could i solve this problem ？

Comment: Print the whole stack trace of error. Also the `dtype=object` is not a parameter, it is just information about array on its left.

Comment: /Users/liumengyang/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:515: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
...
ValueError: Unknown label type: array([-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -2, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1,
       0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1], dtype=object)

Comment: This is just last line in stack trace. You should post complete one which starts from the line in your code and then goes all the way to error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-111-bb129cf7885a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Volumes/sogou_baidu.py', wdir='/Volumes/predict')

  File "/Users/liumengyang/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/liumengyang/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

Comment: File "/Volumes/sogou_baidu.py", line 148, in <module>
    lr.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain)

  File "/Users/liumengyang/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py", line 1143, in fit
    check_classification_targets(y)

  File "/Users/liumengyang/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 173, in check_classification_targets
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y)

Comment: ValueError: Unknown label type: array([-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -2, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1,
       0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1], dtype=object)

Comment: Show some samples of y_train and which version of scikit are you using?

Comment: samples:R1       R2        R3        R4       R5     Y     :-3         -1          0          0          0  -1; 0         -3          0          2          0  -1;0          1          1          2         -2   1......

Comment: version is 0.17.1

Comment: What is R1, R2, .. and why is Y a 2d array?

Comment: try using `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`

Comment: Please, show us `columns`?